# If label doesn't fit in the div of treemap Highcharts it should wrap to second line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, treemap

[JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/irkhaladkar/qsnty6w1/)

Highcharts.chart('container', {

```
series: [{
        useHTML:true,
    type: 'treemap',
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    data: [{
        name: 'A',
        value: 6,
        colorValue: 1
    }, {
        name: 'B',
        value: 6,
        colorValue: 2
    }, {
        name: 'C',
        value: 4,
        colorValue: 3
    }, 
    {
        name: 'Gnscweoihciohoihrioghoierhgoierhoiehgoirehgoirehoih',
        value: 1,
        colorValue: 7
    }]
}],
title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
}
```

});

I tried using HTML:true property but its not helping. Word-Break is also not getting applied

Comment: You can use `<br>` tag in between word, it will work when `useHTML is true`

Answer (score 0):

There need to be 2 updates:

**1. You have to add `dataLabels` property inside `series` property**

*You added `useHTML: ture` property outside `dataLabels`!, so use that like below:*

```
dataLabels: {
    useHTML: true,
    // this is optional formatter, if you need more editing on text with html tags and css then you can use
    formatter() {
        return '<div>'+this.point.name+'</div>';
    }
},
```

**2. Add `css` for data label**

```
.highcharts-data-label span {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

**Check the working example in your code content:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            useHTML: true,
            // this is optional formatter, if you need more editing on text with html tags and css then you can use
            formatter() {
                return '<div>'+this.point.name+'</div>';
            }
        },
        type: 'treemap',
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        data: [{
            name: 'A',
            label: "A",
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 1
        }, {
            name: 'B',
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'C',
            value: 4,
            colorValue: 3
        }, {
            name: 'D',
            value: 3,
            colorValue: 4
        }, {
            name: 'E',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 5
        }, {
            name: 'F',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 6
        }, {
            name: 'This is demo of my code, are you happy',
            value: 1,
            colorValue: 7
        }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
    }
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

. .highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}

.highcharts-data-label span {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Tree maps are great tools for comparing values that are part
        of a whole, or for showing hierarchical data. This example
        is a simple tree map with no hierarchy, showing the value
        differences with rectangle sizes and using a color axis.
    </p>
</figure>
```

**Note:** *Please don't use such big words "Gnscweoihciohoihrioghoierhgoierhoiehgoirehgoirehoih" that you have used in your example, use meaningful and real words, so you will get better solution and output!*

Comment: yepp but not working in my machine some other method?

Comment: `not working in my machine` will not help, verify your code and debug on it.

Comment: using `formatter` callback is unnecessary, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wkpjfdsr/

Comment: @sebastianWedzel, Its optional, if you want more editing on text with html tags and style, and i have checked your demo on this link, you have used `Gnscweoihcioho ihrioghoier hgoierhoiehgoi rehgoirehoih` name in bar, my suggestion is please try to use original words or content it will give you better solutions.